# Symbolic meanings in Dogen's Fugen zazengi

Tags: zen

What is the symbolic meaning behind "the tiger takes to the mountain" in Dogen's [Fugen zazengi](https://web.stanford.edu/group/scbs/sztp3/translations/gongyo_seiten/translations/part_3/fukan_zazengi.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The tiger is in his home in the mountains (in the Eastern imagination), dropping off body and mind you return to the natural state.

Comment: Yes. In the line before, he mentions the dragon taking to the water.

Comment: Yes, you pretty much become yourself. Beautiful question.

Comment: The dragon is a kind of serpent which is a symbol of wisdom.

Comment: In addition, consider that when Dogen wrote his works, literacy was mostly reserved to the warrior class in Japan. For this reason, it may also hint to the reverse of [Sun-Tzu's fifteenth stratagem](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Thirty-Six_Strategies), called "Lure the Tiger Out of the Mountains".